# Mock private static method in final class using PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a final class with private static method which is invoked inside another static method

```
public final class GenerateResponse{
      private static Map<String, String> getErrorDetails(JSONObject jsonObject) {
         // implementation
      }

      public static String method1(params...){
         Map<String, String> map = getErrorDetails(new JsonObject());

         // implementation
      }
}
```

I need to mock the private static method call `getErrorDetails()`, but my test is calling the actual method. Here is my code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(GenerateResponse.class)
public class GenerateResponseTest{

@Test
public void testFrameQtcErrorResponse() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> errorDtls = new HashMap<String, String>();

    PowerMockito.spy(GenerateResponse.class);
    PowerMockito.doReturn(errorDtls).when(GenerateResponse.class, "getErrorDetails", JSONObject.class);
    String response = GenerateResponse.method1(params...);
}
```

Comment: Try adding `PowerMockito.mockStatic(GenerateResponse.class)`

Comment: still the actual method is getting called

Comment: @HAR pls accept my answer if it is working for you.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an argument matcher in the `when`method. I've modified your code a little bit to run the test case.

**Actual method**

```
public final class GenerateResponse{

    private static Map<String, String> getErrorDetails(JSONObject jsonObject) {
       return null;
    }

    public static String method1() {
    Map<String, String> map = getErrorDetails(new JSONObject());
    return map.get("abc");
    }
}
```

**Test method**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(GenerateResponse.class)
public class GenerateResponseTest {

@Test
public void testFrameQtcErrorResponse() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> errorDtls = new HashMap<String, String>();
    errorDtls.put("abc", "alphabets");

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(GenerateResponse.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

    PowerMockito.doReturn(errorDtls).when(GenerateResponse.class,
            "getErrorDetails", Matchers.any(JSONObject.class));

    String response = GenerateResponse.method1();

    System.out.println("response =" + response);

   }

 }
```

**Output**

```
response =alphabets
```

Comment: I LOVE YOU. You saved me.